# How to make a new image appear when a button is pressed Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a game where if you press a button, an image will pop up, but I can't figure it out how to do it. Maybe I'm putting it in with a plus indent, or messing up something, I have no clue on what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated! Anyways, here's the code: (Important part is the `number_one` function)

```
import pygame
import os
import random



WIDTH, HEIGHT = (1024, 768)
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Joe mama")

number = [0, 1, 2]

# Button class
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)

    def draw(self):
        #Draw button on screen
        WIN.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))






def number_one():
    # Picture Variables
    kerdes1 = pygame.image.load("Zene/1/Kérdés-1.png")
    A_select = pygame.image.load("Zene/1/A megjelölve.png")
    B_select = pygame.image.load("Zene/1/B megjelölve.png")
    C_select = pygame.image.load("Zene/1/C megjelölve.png")
    D_select = pygame.image.load("Zene/1/D megjelölve.png")
    WIN.blit(kerdes1, (0, 0))
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                WIN.blit(A_select, (0, 0))
                print("pressed up")

def number_two():
    kerdes2 = pygame.image.load("Zene/2/Kérdés-2.png")
    WIN.blit(kerdes2, (0, 0))




while len(number) > 0:
    if len(number) == 0:
        break
    result = random.choice(number)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if result == 1:
                    print("1")
                    number.remove(1)
                    number_one()
                    print(number)
                pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. Now it works so that the mouse clicks on the image and the index is raised.

According to the index, they drew a picture from the list "images"

Here is my code example:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

WIDTH, HEIGHT = (1024, 768)
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Joe mama")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    def draw(self):
        WIN.blit(self.image, self.rect)


button_img = pygame.image.load("button_image.png")
A_select = pygame.image.load("image1.png")
B_select = pygame.image.load("image2.png")

images = [A_select, B_select]


def number_one(index):
    WIN.blit(images[index], (WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2))


button = Button(100, 100, button_img)
index = -1
while True:
    WIN.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if button.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    index += 1

    button.draw()
    if index >= 0:
        number_one(index % len(images))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

If something is not according to your ideas, write a comment and edit the assignment.

I hope it will help you, Adam